# Functionality put in a convenience init - unusable in sub-classes?

Tags: cocoa, swift

Isn't functionality put in a convenience init - unusable in sub-classes?

If so, why are the Cocoa's interfaces for Swift defining so many initializers as convenience.

For example - I have a sub-class of NSWindowController and I would like to create a designated init, which will not get any parameters and should directly know what NIB file to instantiate with.

But I don't have any access to super.init's/methods to get the already implemented behaviour and build up on it. Here is the definition of the inits of NSWindowController:

```
class NSWindowController : NSResponder, NSCoding, NSSeguePerforming, NSObjectProtocol {
    init(window: NSWindow?)
    init?(coder: NSCoder)

    convenience init(windowNibName: String)
    convenience init(windowNibName: String, owner: AnyObject)
    convenience init(windowNibPath: String, owner: AnyObject)
    // ...
}
```

Instead I am forced to reimplement the NIB loading, thus duplicating and potentially getting it wrong.

Edit:

Here is a small passage from a [blogpost](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-04-05-windows-and-window-controllers.html) by Mike Ash, mentioning NSWindowController subclasses and the reasoning behind what I do in my case is exactly the same:

*NSWindowController provides a initWithWindowNibName: method. However, your subclass is built to work with only a single nib, so it's pointless to make clients specify that nib name. Instead, we'll provide a plain init method that does the right thing internally. Simply override it to call super and provide the nib name:*

```
- (id)init
{
    return [super initWithWindowNibName: @"MAImportantThingWindow"];
}
```

So it's possible in ObjectiveC, but how can this be done in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convenience initializers are inherited in subclasses. They can be overriden, too.

In order to call init(windowNibName: String), you need to declare a convenience initializer to call it from, and you should call it on **self**, rather than **super**:

```
class MAImportantThingWindowController : NSWindowController {

    override convenience init() {
        self.init(windowNibName: "MAImportantThingWindow")
    }
}
```